# Custom Voice Action

Tags: applications, voice-recognition, java

Can i make the google assistant of my android phone to perform custom actions?
For example: Ok google. open barrier via "AppName"?
I have tried the system actions, but neither one matches my need. So is it doable to create my custom voice action?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is creating  your own commands for your Google Assistant using IFTTT, as explained on https://ifttt.com/google_assistant